# Splitting a string read from Serial into parts

Tags: eeprom

Is there any method with which I can split a string given by `Serial.read()` into an array of 3 items: [command, address, message], to write it to EEPROM?

Thanks.

Comment: `Serial.read()` reads a single byte, not a string.

Comment: Ah!! , so How can i manage a string like : read 13; ps: 13 is address 
or another string like: Write 13 15 where 15 is the message?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is to collect your serial input into a string.

If your incoming data use a separator, then you can take advantage of the useful function "readStringUntil".

For example, if your separator is comma (,):

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  var1 = Serial.readStringUntil(','); // writes in the string all the inputs till a comma
  Serial.read(); 
  var2 = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
  Serial.read(); 
  var3 = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); // writes in the string all the inputs till the end of line character
}
```

At this point you have your data in 3 different variables and you can use the standard eeprom library to store. Don't forget you will need to declare the variables and to initialize the Serial.

A faster way is to save the whole input in string and process it when ready.

Much better it will be if you use interrupts attached on the Serial input, so you can keep free your loop from waiting data. This can't be done with the standard Serial library but you can use this library:

https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoHWSerial

It works really well, we use it to collect data from GPS receivers at very high speed and it's fast.

N.B. eeprom is limited in the numbers of reads and writes it can support before risk a failure. Even 100,000 reads/writes sounds a big numnber, if you write the data once every second your eeprom will die in just 27 hours, a day of life. Try to write data only when it's strictly necessary and read data as well only when you start the procedure that uses those data, once.

Answer (score 2):

That's the code I used to fix this issue.

```cpp
#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      String command = Serial.readStringUntil(' '); // writes in the string all the inputs till a comma
      Serial.read(); 
      String addressStr = Serial.readStringUntil(' ');
      Serial.read(); 
      String messageStr = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); // writes in the string all the inputs till the end of line character
      int address = addressStr.toInt();
      int message = messageStr.toInt();
      if (command == "Read"){
        Serial.print("Reading from EEPROM->Address: ");
        Serial.print(address);
        Serial.print("\n");
        Serial.print("Content of ");
        Serial.print(address);
        Serial.print("is: ");
        Serial.println(EEPROM.read(address));
      }else if(command == "Write"){
        Serial.print("Writing to EEPROM in Address: ");
        Serial.print(address);
        Serial.println();
        EEPROM.write(address, message);
      }
  }
}
```